# Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

This is my code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Material(
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    child: new Column(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:<Widget>[new GridView.count(crossAxisCount: _column,children: new List.generate(_row*_column, (index) {
          return new Center(
              child: new CellWidget()
          );
        }),)]
    )
  );
}
```

Exception as follows:

```
I/flutter ( 9925): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 9925): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 9925): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 9925): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 9925): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 9925): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter ( 9925): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter ( 9925): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter ( 9925): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter ( 9925): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
I/flutter ( 9925): 
I/flutter ( 9925): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 9925): #0      RenderViewport.performResize.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:827:15)
I/flutter ( 9925): #1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:880:6)
I/flutter ( 9925): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1555:9)
```

Comment: you can also use simple Container as well instead of Column(mainly for more than one child widget.)

Comment: Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      child: new Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child:  new GridView.count(crossAxisCount: _column,children: new List.generate(_row*_column, (index) {
          return new Center(
              child: new CellWidget()
          );
        })
        ),
      )
    ); --This code also does not helps @Napolean

Comment: try adding mainAxisSize to max under Column, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 747, accepted):

**Add this two lines**

```dart
    ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
    ...
```

In this code snippet, have a `ListView.builder` with the following properties:

1. `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`: This property specifies the scrolling direction of the list. In this case, it is set to `Axis.vertical`, which means the list will scroll vertically. You can also set it to `Axis.horizontal` if you want the list to scroll horizontally.
2. `shrinkWrap: true`: By default, a `ListView` takes up as much space as it can along its main axis. However, when you set `shrinkWrap` to `true`, the `ListView` will try to wrap its content and only take up as much space as needed. This can be helpful when you want to include a `ListView` inside another scrollable view or when the size of the list is not predetermined.

Comment: Thanks,just a small advice you can surround the ListView by Flexible to make it scroll-able

Comment: Here is the documentation for `shrinkWrap`
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html

Comment: For future reference, please be aware that, according to the documentation, `shrinkWrap` being set to true can be significantly more expensive if there are a lot of widgets in the list view. Please see this snippet from the documentation:  
  
`Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size because the content can expand and contract during scrolling, which means the size of the scroll view needs to be recomputed whenever the scroll position changes.`

Comment: The `shrinkWrap: true` was expensive and it made my list laggy, and this was solved by surrounding my ListView with a Flexible.

Comment: @BloodLoss I use shrinkWrap: true, my problem is solved but  the scoll does not work on listView..why

Comment: ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         shrinkWrap: true,
    
        )

Answer (score 312):

This generally happens when you try to use a `ListView`/`GridView` inside a `Column`, there are many ways of solving it, I am listing few here.

1. Wrap `ListView` in `Expanded`

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       Expanded( // wrap in Expanded
         child: ListView(...),
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```
2. Wrap `ListView` in `SizedBox` and give a bounded `height`

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       SizedBox(
         height: 400, // fixed height
         child: ListView(...),
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```
3. Use `shrinkWrap: true` in `ListView`.

   ```
   Column(
     children: <Widget>[
       ListView(
         shrinkWrap: true, // use this
       ),
     ],
   )
   ```

Comment: Tried this with a vertical listview containing a horizontal listview.  Only the sizedbox method would work but its too prescriptive on the height.  How else to do this?

Comment: `shrinkWrap: true` did the job

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Any chance you can add the pros and cons of each choice?

Comment: @fractal, I agree, only `SizedBox` solution worked for me as well when placing a `ListView` inside a `Column`.  You can get the device screen size, and set `height` relative to that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61718245/2162226 . Now working, wrap `Widget listView = ListView.builder(..)` this way: `listView = SizedBox(height: _scale.scaledHeight(.43), child: listView);`  for the % of space visibly available on the screen

Comment: For me wrapping GridView in Expanded and specifiying shrinkWap: true for GridView worked, I needed to add both.

Comment: @Munes If that's the case, simply wrap your `GridView` in `Flexible`, you may not need to use `shrinkWrap` then.

Comment: This is the best answer. Just be aware that if the `ListView` has a lot of elements inside and `shrinkWrap` is set to `true`, it is significantly more expensive. Taken from the documentation: `"Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size because the content can expand and contract during scrolling, which means the size of the scroll view needs to be recomputed whenever the scroll position changes."`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad  I use shrinkWrap: true, my problem is solved but the scoll does not work on listView..any idea

Comment: @benten Use other solutions because `shrinkWrap` is only suitable if your `ListView` isn't too long.

Comment: I use this  => physics: ScrollPhysics(), 
it start working

Comment: @benten It's better to remove `shrinkWrap` then if you're adding the `ScrollPhysics`.

Answer (score 56):

So, everyone posted answers but no one cared to explain why:
I'll copy the documentation about `shrinkWrap`:

> Whether the extent of the scroll view in the [scrollDirection] should be
>   determined by the contents being viewed.
>
> If the scroll view does not shrink wrap, then the scroll view will expand
>   to the maximum allowed size in the [scrollDirection]. If the scroll view
>   has unbounded constraints in the [scrollDirection], then [shrinkWrap] must
>   be true.
>
> Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more
>   expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size because the content
>   can expand and contract during scrolling, which means the size of the
>   scroll view needs to be recomputed whenever the scroll position changes.
>
> Defaults to `false`.

So, taking the vocabulary of the docs, **what's happening here is that our `ListView` is in a situation of *unbounded constraints*** (in the direction that we are scrolling), thus the `ListView` will complain that:

> ... a vertical viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in 
>   which to expand.

By simply setting `shrinkWrap` to `true` will make sure that it wraps its size defined by the contents. A sample code to illustrate:

```
// ...
  ListView(
    // Says to the `ListView` that it must wrap its
    // height (if it's vertical) and width (if it's horizontal).
    shrinkWrap: true,
  ),
// ...
```

That's what is going with your code, nonetheless, @Rémi suggestion is the best for this case, using `Align` instead of a `Column`.

Answer (score 41):

put grid view inside `Flexible` or `Expanded` widget

```
return new Material(
    color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
    child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children:<Widget>[
         Flexible(
          child:  GridView.count(crossAxisCount: _column,children: new List.generate(_row*_column, (index) {
          return new Center(
             child: new CellWidget(),
          );
        }),))]
    )
);
```

Comment: Expanded and add `shrinkWrap: true` to GridView.

Answer (score 39):

Although `shrinkWrap` do the thing, but you can't scroll in `ListView`.

If you want scrolling functionality, you can add `physics` property:

```
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
...
```

It is also helpful when you want to extend the scope of scrolling to other widgets of the screen:

```
Column(
  children: [
    ListTile(
    //Some other functionality
    ),
    ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: 10,
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      // Some other functionality
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: This answer worked perfectly where as the top rated answers did not.

Answer (score 37):

## Cause of Viewport Exception

`GridView` / `ListView` **grow** until *constraints* (limits) stop this expansion & then scroll to view items beyond that size.

But `Column` lays out its children *without* any constraints, **completely ignoring its own size and screen size**. There is infinite space inside of `Column`.

`Viewport was given unbounded height` exception occurs because `Grid/ListView` expands to infinity inside a `Column`.

`Flexible/Expanded` exist to give `Column` children constraints based `Column's` size.  (These two widgets cannot be used anywhere else, except inside `Row` and `Column`.)

Inside a `Flexible/Expanded` widget in `Column`, `Grid/ListView` only uses remaining space not taken by other, non-flexible widgets, which get laid out first.  (See bottom for layout phases info.)

## `shrinkWrap` is not a good solution

Using `shrinkWrap: true` on `ListView` inside a `Column` isn't really helpful as:

- `ListView` no longer scrolls
- `ListView` can still overflow

A `ListView` tall enough to show all of its items, will not scroll.  Arguably defeats the purpose of using a `ScrollView` widget (parent class of `ListView`).

In `Column` layout phase 1 (see bottom for explanation of layout phases), `ListView` can be any height it wants (there are no constraints).
A `ListView` with `shrinkWrap:true` will grow in height to show all its items.
With enough items, a `shrinkWrapped` `ListView` will grow & grow (it never scrolls) to overflow whatever `Column` is inside, be it screen or other tighter constraint.

###### Shouldn't `shrinkWrap` just make `ListView` only as big as its items *OR* remaining space (up to screen height), and then scroll?

That would make intuitive sense, but inside a `Column` in phase 1 **layout is done in *unbounded space***.

So, remaining space is unlimited/infinite.  A max height is never reached. `shrinkWrap:true` just keeps growing `Column` height as items are added until overflowing the screen (or other smaller constraint).

##### Example `shrinkWrap:true` Overflow

Here's an example of adding items to a shrinkwrapped `ListView` in a `Column` until its height is taller than the screen, creating an overflow warning area:

(just keep pressing the **+** sign Floating Action Button)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColumnListViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ColumnListViewPageState createState() => _ColumnListViewPageState();
}

class _ColumnListViewPageState extends State<ColumnListViewPage> {
  int _count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Column & ListView'),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _count++;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)
          ),
          /// // without center, Column will be as narrow as possible
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          /// Column is forced (constrained) to match screen dimension,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text('Inner (Nested) Column'),
              ListView.separated( // ← should be wrapped in Expanded
                itemCount: _count,
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 38.0),
                  child: Text('Row $index'),
                ),
                shrinkWrap: true, // should be removed
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

###### For `GridView/ListView` in a `Column`, wrapping within `Expanded` or `Flexible` is likely the safest solution.

---

### Expanded / Flexible

`Expanded` and `Flexible` can only be used inside `Column` (and its siblings like `Row`, etc.).

They must be used as immediate children of `Column`.  We can't "nest" `Expanded`/`Flexible` in `SizedBox` or other widgets.  Only directly under `Column` as immediate children.

Inside `Column`, placing `ListView/GridView` in `Expanded` or `Flexible` ensures it will use only available space, rather than infinite space.

```
Column
→ Expanded
  → ListView
```

`ListView/GridView` inside `Expanded/Flexible` in a `Column` doesn't need `shrinkWrap` because it is constrained (given a max. height) by the `Expanded/Flexible` widget.  So when that constrained/defined height is used up, `ListView/GridView` will stop growing & begin scrolling.

---

## Column Layout Phases

`Column` lays out children in 2 phases:

- 1st without constraints (unbounded space)
- 2nd with remaining space based on `Column's` parent

#### Phase 1

Any `Column` child **not** inside `Flexible` or `Expanded` will be laid out in phase 1, in infinite, limitless space *completely ignoring screen size*.

Widgets that need a vertical boundary/constraint to limit their growth (e.g. `ListView`) will cause a `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height` exception in phase 1 as there *are no vertical bounds in unbounded space*.

Most widgets have intrinsic size.  `Text` for example, is only as high as its content & font size/style.  It doesn't try to grow to fill a space.  Defined-height widgets play well in Phase 1 of `Column` layout.

#### Phase 2

Any widget that grows to fill bounds, should be put in a `Flexible` or `Expanded` for Phase 2 layout.

Phase 2 calculates `Column's` remaining space from its parent constraints ***minus*** space used in Phase 1. This remaining space is provided to Phase 2 children as constraints.

`ListView` for example, will only grow to use remaining space & stop, avoiding viewport exceptions.

[More info on `Column` layout algorithm and how `Expanded` works within it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718208/2301224).

Answer (score 17):

This situation typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.

In my case i use GridView inside of Column and that error throws.

GridView widget has `shrinkWrap` property/named parameter, to set it `true` my problem is fixed.

```
GridView.count(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  // rest of code
)
```

Comment: I use shrinkWrap: true, my problem is solved but the scoll does not work on listView..why

Answer (score 12):

Don't use `Column` for single child alignment. Use `Align` instead.

```dart
new Align(
  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
  child: new GridView(),
)
```

Comment: It though solved my error but still, I am not able to center my GridView vertically. It shows same as before. Tried all flags for Alignment.* What I am missing?

Answer (score 10):

There are a lot of answer but each one have its own limitation. everyone is saying use  **shrinkWrap: true**. Yes you should use it but the effect of these code is when you will scroll the list, it will automatically move to top item, means scroll back to top.
So perfect solution is use shrinkwrap with **physics** then only the list will be able to scroll smoothly.

```
      shrinkWrap: true,          //
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),  // both line is mandatory
```

If you want to see other example of Listview.builder with column as a child and list can be scroll vertically then you can [see the example here](https://www.dripcoding.com/animate-text-flutter/) - arrange multiple text in a vertical list.

Answer (score 8):

**Adding this two lines**

> ListView.builder(
> scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
> shrinkWrap: true,

...

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to post another answer because many answers (including the accepted one!) suggest using `shrinkWrap: true` in `ListView.builder`. While this removes the error, this solution is [**NOT** ideal for performance reasons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html) for this case. Flutter designed `ListView` with infinite size specifically to discourage this behaviour only when necessary!

> Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size because the content can expand and contract during scrolling, which means the size of the scroll view needs to be recomputed whenever the scroll position changes.

In some cases/devices, this property caused glitchy scrolls and animation lag in my projects. Even if the lag isn't noticeable, this property does hinder scroll performance.

The OP shows that he is creating a **small (finite) number of children** for `ListView`. If we want to resolve the error for these lists, Google [recommends](https://medium.com/flutter/how-to-debug-layout-issues-with-the-flutter-inspector-87460a7b9db) using a `Flexible` widget, i.e. `Expanded` (a `Flexible` with flex 1) on the list itself.

```
Expanded(
    child: ListView(
        ...
    ),
)
```

There are other layout issues here, but the vertical viewport unbounded height is because the `ListView` doesn't have a parent that bounds its size.

Comment: While true, there are many use cases where a ListView is legitimately surrounded with a parent like Semantics (see the image_picker example) and the shrinkWrap performs a valuable role in those cases. Thanks this was very helpful to understand the trade-offs. You may want to add ScrollPhysics to test the performance impact. Expanded needs to be nested as an immediate child of a flexible widget which can sometimes limit its use.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways which we can solve the above issues

**1. Using Flexible Widget,**

The `Flexible` widget can be used inside Row, Column, and Flex.The flexibility to expand to fill the available space in the main axis (e.g., horizontally for a [Row] or vertically for a [Column])

But, remember, unlike `Expanded`, The `Flexible` widget does not require the child to fill available space. So, it's always better to use `Flexible`.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible( 
      child: ListView(...),
    ),
  ],
)
```

**2. Using shrinkWrap: true**

Using `shrinkWrap` as true, we tell the Listview to render its List to available space, not take below remaining screen.

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, 
    ),
  ],
)
```

---

Also, `physics` attribute can be used to allow/disallow scrolling of `Listview`

**Stop Scrolling**

```
 ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, 
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    ),
```

**Allow Scrolling**

```
 ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, 
      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
    ),
```

Answer (score 4):

I faced this problem because I wanted to display a `GridView` inside a `ListView`, and the solution was by adding the following not only in the `ListView` but also in the `GridView` as well:

1. `shrinkwrap: true`
2. `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: I see, but all answers for adding those steps just in list view, i was already  tried it and the error was the same without any change. After adding those not only in listview, but also in gridview it was working. i just saying what happened to me

Comment: Got it. I'd edit the answer then to make it a bit clear. Something like: "_I faced this problem cause I wanted to display a `GridView` inside a `ListView`, and the solution was by adding the following not only in the `ListView` but also in the `GridView` as well:_"

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to clarify through my answer in this way, and thank you for your understanding

Answer (score 4):

```dart
ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      height: 100,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      color: Colors.pinkAccent,

                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow, the `shrinkWrap: true` is already answered on top level and also avoid using this when ever possible

Answer (score 3):

If you still face this problem in 2021 ..here is the best and easy solution

```
      ListView.builder(
         scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
         shrinkWrap: true,
     //     itemExtent: 400, use this if you give hight of your items
        physics: ScrollPhysics(),)
```

> their are many solution .. but they have problem.. like when we use ListView and use its property shrinkWrap .then one thing you many notice the scroll does not work on listView so you must use  physics: ScrollPhysics()

Answer (score 3):

FINALLY SOLVED!

I had a problem where were 2 nested Listview.builders inside a column.
The problem that layout calculates dynamically and you cannot set the fix height for the ListView.builder (via SizedBox for example).

To avoid this problem, try:

1. to change your Column with a widget **ListView.**
2. Then to make sure that you take all available space you have to wrap it with the **Expanded** widget. (or try Padding instead, it works also sometimes, but i don't understand why).
3. Then set to the **ListView** the property **shrinkWrap** to **true** to limit it from infinity.
   And inside **Listvie.builder** set also **shrinkWrap** to **true** to limit from infinity even here. And here also you have to add **physics: ScrollPhysics()** to make it scrollable.

Here a simple example, but it works for more complicated structure of course.

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: 100,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text('index is $i'),
                          );
                        })
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here also en example for nested ListView.builder:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: 100,
                        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              Center(
                                child: Text(
                                  'index is $i',
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                                ),
                              ),
                              ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: 4,
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemBuilder: (context, j) {
                                    return Center(
                                      child:
                                          Text('nested ListView index is: $j'),
                                    );
                                  }),
                              Divider(
                                height: 1,
                                thickness: 2,
                                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 400,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.greenAccent),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working as expected

Answer (score 2):

```
    Container(
       height: 100,
       child: ListView.builder(
       scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
       physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
       shrinkWrap: true,
       itemCount: 5,
       itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       return Text("Hello World $index");
      },
    ),
  );
```

Comment: If the scroll view has unbounded constraints in the scrollDirection, then shrinkWrap must be true.

Answer (score 1):

test this one for second listview

```
ListView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add my solution that worked in my case where I have vertical list view together with other buttons and texts on the same screen:

```
Flexible(
child:  
  ListView.builder(
  // make sure to add the following lines:  
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
  // the rest of your list view code
 ) // ListView
) // Flexible
```

This solution works well particularly when you have other widgets on the SAME SCREEN. In this particular case, "*Expand*" or "*Flexible*" alone will not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a widget called Center. It should help you achive what you want to do (center it vertically). [Official Documentation for Center widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Center-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also meet this error, because the code like this

```dart
return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return CircleManagerSettingItem(widget.membersInfo[index]);
              },
              separatorBuilder: (_, index) => DD(
                    height: 1,
                    paddingLeft: 10,
                    paddingRight: 10,
                  ),
              itemCount: (widget.membersInfo.length)),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

remove the `Column` inside the `Container` then Ok.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I had to wrap the ListView inside a Container and give this container a specific Height

Answer (score 0):

I have made a custom function to solve your problem.
You can directly use this function in your code base:

```
Widget horizontalListView(height, width, color, child, margin) {
return Column(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 200,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemBuilder: (context,index) {
          return Container(
            height: height,
            width: width,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(margin),
            color: color,
            child: child
          );
        }
      ),
    ),
  ],
 );
})
```

P.S. Sorry for bad alignment of code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `CustomScrollView`

you can try `SliverFillRemaining`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck

Comment: That answer is the best answer in case of CustomScrollView. and it does not need explanation since the widget used is self explanatory. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can put Expanded() as a parent of that widget too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `ListView` inside `SingleChildScrollView`, just set `shrinkWrap: True` and `physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in the `ListView`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and kept the ListView **scrollabe**

```
return ListView(
shrinkWrap: true, //<-
physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(), //<-
children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
            title: Text("Exp1")),
 ListTile(
            title: Text("Exp2"))]);
```