# Flutter: "RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded"

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to have a `ListView` inside another widget when I wrap `FutureBuilder` in a `Column` in order to have a simple `Row`. I get this error:

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (13816): RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
I/flutter (13816): When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height constraint, for example, if it is
I/flutter (13816): in a vertical scrollable, it will try to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a
I/flutter (13816): flex on a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to fill the remaining
I/flutter (13816): space in the vertical direction.
I/flutter (13816): These two directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its child, the child
I/flutter (13816): cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
I/flutter (13816): Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible
I/flutter (13816): children (using Flexible rather than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
I/flutter (13816): themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would otherwise be forced to take, and
I/flutter (13816): then will cause the RenderFlex to shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
I/flutter (13816): constraints provided by the parent.
I/flutter (13816): If this message did not help you determine the problem, consider using debugDumpRenderTree():
```

My code:

```dart
class ActivityShowTicketReplies extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> ticketData;

  ActivityShowTicketReplies({@required this.ticketData});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => ActivityShowTicketRepliesState();
}

class ActivityShowTicketRepliesState extends State<ActivityShowTicketReplies> {
  TicketsTableData get _ticket => TicketsTableData.fromJson(json.decode(widget.ticketData.values.toList()[0][0].toString()));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScopedModel(
      model: CounterModel(),
      child: Directionality(
        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      color: Colors.indigo,
                      onPressed: () => BlocProvider.of<AppPagesBloc>(context).dispatch(FragmentNavigateEvent(routeName: FRAGMENT_NEW_TICKET)),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'new ticket',
                          style: AppTheme(context).caption().copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              FutureBuilder(
                future: Provider.of<TicketRepliesTableDao>(context).find(ticketId: _ticket.id),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      final List<TicketRepliesTableData> ticketReplies = snapshot.data;
                      if (ticketReplies.isNotEmpty) {
                        return Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Card(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                              color: Colors.grey[50],
                              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: InkWell(
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Column(
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
                                          child: ListTile(
                                            title: Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                                              child: Text(
                                                'subject',
                                                style: AppTheme(context).caption().copyWith(fontFamily: 'ShabnamBold'),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            subtitle: Text(
                                              _ticket.subject,
                                              style: AppTheme(context).caption(),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Container(
                                          height: 30.0,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          color: Colors.grey[200],
                                          child: Row(
                                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    Align(
                                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                      child: Container(
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                            minWidth: 70.0,
                                          ),
                                          height: 20.0,
                                          width: 70.0,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              color: Colors.green[200],
                                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                                topRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
                                                bottomRight: Radius.circular(5.0),
                                              )),
                                          child: Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              'status',
                                              style: AppTheme(context).overLine().copyWith(fontFamily: 'ShabnamBold', color: Colors.black),
                                            ),
                                          )),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                onTap: () {},
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return Card(
                                    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                      child: Column(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Row(
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              Text(
                                                ticketReplies[index].createdAt,
                                                style: AppTheme(context).caption().copyWith(fontFamily: 'ShabnamLight'),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          ListTile(
                                            title: Text(ticketReplies[index].reply),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                itemCount: ticketReplies.length,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'there isn't any reply message',
                            style: AppTheme(context).caption(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    } else {
                      return _loader(context, 'no reply');
                    }
                  } else
                    return _loader(context, Strings.pleaseWait);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _loader(BuildContext context,String message) {
    return Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ColorLoader3(
              radius: 25.0,
              dotRadius: 5.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
              child: Text(
                Strings.pleaseWait,
                style: AppTheme(context).caption().copyWith(color: Colors.red[900]),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Probably the most annoying error in flutter.

Comment: Probably where I loose more than 50% of my time.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Wrap your `Column` inside an `Expanded` or `SizedBox` (with some `height`) like this:

```dart
Expanded(
  child: Column(...)
)
```

**OR**

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 200, // Some height
  child: Column(...),
)
```

---

> **Note** that a `Flex` class or sub-class (like `Column`) should not be child of other `Flex` classes, and their parent class needs to be of type `Flexible` (i.e. inherit it, like `Expanded`), **else, `Flex`-class gets unbounded** (and remaining space cannot be calculated) which causes no direct issue till yet another child tries to calculate and/or fill space.

Comment: Please answer why that error message occurs? What's the meaning?

Answer (score 173):

## Explanation

How wrapping a `Column > Expanded` with another `Expanded` solves the error.

#### RenderFlex Unbounded Error

A common nested Column-Expanded hierarchy that gets the `"RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded"` error:

```
Screen
  → Column
    → Column
      → Expanded → ERROR
```

What's happening:

```
Screen
  ↓ constraint ↓ (Screen)
  Column
    Text_A (fixed height: no constraint needed) → OK
    Column 
      ↓ constraint ↓ (unbounded)
      Text_B (fixed height) → OK
      Expanded: calc. height = unbounded - Text_B → ERROR
```

During layout, a `Column` performs (in order):

- fixed-height (i.e. null/zero flex-factor) widget layouts *in unbounded space*, then...
- flex-factor sized widgets, calculating remaining space from the parent (i.e. incoming constraints) & the fixed size widgets

`Text_A` above is fixed-height. It doesn't use incoming constraints for layout.

`Expanded` though, is a flex-factor widget, sizing itself on *remaining* space, after fixed-size items are laid out.  This requires an incoming constraint (parent size) to do subtraction:

```
  parent size (constraint) - fixed-items size = remaining space
```

The 1st `Column` gets constraints from the device screen (provided via `Scaffold`, etc.).

But, the 2nd `Column` (the nested one) is laid out in *unbounded* space.

Remaining space cannot be calculated:

```
  unbounded - Text_B = unbounded (error)
```

#### Why is a Nested `Column` Unbounded?

```
Screen
  → Column
    → Column
      → Expanded
```

Copied from `Column` SDK source documentation, Step 1:

```
/// 1. Layout each child with a null or zero flex factor (e.g., those that are not
///    [Expanded]) with unbounded vertical constraints
```

The 2nd, nested `Column`:

- is a *child of* `Column` (the 1st one, obviously), and...
- has *zero or null flex factor*

The second point is easy to miss/not see, but `Column` is **not** a flex-factor widget.

Checking SDK source...

`Column` extends `Flex` class.

`Flex`, does ***not*** have a `flex` field / flex factor.  Only *`Flexible`* class and its children are flex factor widgets.

So the 2nd `Column` is laid out in unbounded constraints because it is not a flex-factor widget.  Those unbounded constraints are used to layout `Text_B` widget (a fixed-size or null flex factor widget), then `Expanded` tries to calculate remaining space.  When trying to calculate remaining space with an unbounded constraint....

```
  unbounded - Text_B = unbounded (error)
```

`Expanded` explodes

### **`Flexible`**

To be hyper-repetitive: `Flexible`, **is** ***the*** flex-factor widget with a `flex` field/factor.

`Expanded` and `Spacer` are the only child classes of `Flexible` (that I know of).

So `Expanded`, `Spacer`, and `Flexible` are the only flex-factor widgets and

`Flexible != Flex`

---

#### The Fix - Adding Bounds

Fixing the widget tree:

```
Screen
  → Column
    → Expanded ← new
      → Column
        → Expanded → OK
```

Why this works...

```
Screen
  ↓ constraint ↓
  Column
    Text_A ↑ fixed-size ↑
    ↓ constraint ↓ (calculated: Screen height - Text_A height)
    Expanded_A
      ↓ constraint ↓ (Screen - Text_A)
      Column
        Text_B ↑ fixed-size ↑
        Expanded_B: calc. height = (Screen - Text_A) - Text_B = remaining space → OK
```

In this case...
After fixed-items are laid out (`Text_A`), remaining space is calculated for `Expanded_A`:

```
parent size (screen) - fixed-items (Text_A) = remaining space
```

Now `Expanded_A` has a defined amount of space.

`Expanded_A` provides its size for use by the child `Column` calculating remaining space for `Expanded_B` after laying out `Text_B`.

```
parent size - fixed-items = remaining space
                  ↓
(Screen - Text_A) - (Text_B) = remaining space for Expanded_B
```

Now all flex-factor relative sized widgets (i.e. `Expanded_A`, `Expanded_B`) have bounded constraints with which to calculate their layout size.

Note that you can use `Flexible` interchangably here with `Expanded`.  It calculates remaining space the same way as `Expanded`.  It just doesn't force children to fit its size, so they can be smaller if they wish.

## Copy/paste Code Action:

#### NOT OK

```
/// Unbounded constraint: NOT OK
class RenderFlexUnboundedPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text('Column > Column > Text_A'),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text('Column > Column > Expanded_A')) // explosions
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### OK

```
/// Constraints provided: OK
class RenderFlexPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('Column > Text_A'),
          Expanded( // Expanded_A
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text('Column > Expanded_A > Column > Text_B'),
                Expanded( // Expanded_B
                    child: Text('Column > Expanded_A > Column > Expanded_B'))
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In short, a `Flex` class or sub-class (like `Column`) can not be child of other `Flex` classes, and their parent class needs to be of type `Flexible` (i.e. inherit it), else, they are unbounded (and remaining space cannot be calculated) which causes no direct issue till yet another child tries to calculate and fill it

Comment: Your answer is a great one. I wish I could give it extra points.

Comment: Your answer explains it great and with such an attention to detail that it's better then most of "member-only" stories on Medium.

Comment: Very detailed answer. Ty!

Answer (score 17):

If you want to solve `Render Flex` issue, try:

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Column(
        children: [
```

Answer (score 4):

Setting `columns` `mainAxisSize` to **min** solves in case of `SingleChildScrollView` since no one acknowledged this so..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: he means to use```              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach never fails me:

```
Card(
    child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus finibus luctus tortor id pulvinar. Donec sollicitudin, dui vitae aliquam tristique, eros risus commodo enim, eget lobortis arcu velit ac arcu. "),
                Text("Nunc tristique, ex ut volutpat feugiat, nulla nibh iaculis lectus, laoreet auctor justo tellus quis mi. Praesent ut interdum sem. Donec eget finibus augue, et vehicula elit. Praesent eu euismod arcu, eu maximus tellus. Ut diam est, sodales nec enim a, pharetra lobortis erat."),
            ]
     )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was happening because I did not use `Expanded` widget. However, that also did not help to achieve the result. Instead, I used `SizedBox` with `height` property like following:

```
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
```

This easily solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I want to offer up another solution seeing that I just had to overcome this problem myself. For context, this is the over-simplified structure for the widget that was throwing this error:

```
Container
  child: Column
         children: Column, Spacer, Row
```

In my case, I wanted the `Container` to expand with the content that is inside of it. Initially, I defined a height and width for this container, but because I wanted it to dynamically expand, I removed those constraints. The error was then raised:

> “RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded”

My problem was the `Spacer` in between the rows. The children of the first `Column` are trying to expand indefinitely (hence "non-zero flex") because the `Spacer` was pushing each child to the vertical bounds of its parent. This isn't usually a problem, but ***there are no bounds on the parent for the spacer to push the children to***. This is because their parent, the first `Column`, was *also trying to expand* because the `Container` was not given a height or width property.

My fix was to simply replace the `Spacer` with a `SizedBox` that has a finite height:

```
Container
  child: Column
         children: Column, SizedBox(height: 10), Row
```

Comment: Im having the same problem but i dont want to use SizedBox since i want to position the widget at the end of the screen and using sizedBox seems quite iresponsive. I send the code in paste bin and commented where im trying to put Spacer.

https://pastebin.com/MtLTYmkr

Comment: @LearnFlutter unfortunately I don't think you can get away with using a spacer in this situation because the parent column isn't given a height. The spacer would not know how much to expand because its parent (the parent column) doesn't have a set height. So, it just tries to expand infinitely and that's why you get the error.

Comment: I actually found the solution and this works perfectly

https://pastebin.com/h9NWRNRa

Comment: @LearnFlutter well done! Glad you were able to find a solution.