# Scrollable Column and ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to have a Column and ListView.builder to be scrollable using the SingleChildScrollView. I tried wrapping both the Column or the SingleChildScrollView with Expanded but I'm still not winning. I just want the ListView.builder and the Container above it to be scrollable. Please help...

I am getting an error that says : **RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded**.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ionicons/ionicons.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../widgets/product_item.dart';
import '../providers/products.dart';

class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = productsData.items;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Ionicons.notifications_outline,
          ),
        ),
        title: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/logo.png',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Ionicons.cart_outline,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 140,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26.0),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: const [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15.0,
                    top: 20.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Place Order',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemCount: products.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
                  products[i].id,
                  products[i].name,
                  products[i].size,
                  products[i].price,
                  products[i].image,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, tell us more about your Scrollable behavior. What do you want to achieve? What elements should be Scrollable? Include more details and if possible printscreens. Also, it looks like a complex layout being build with basic and limited widgets, take a look on `CustomScrollView` and `Slivers`

Comment: For an explanation on the Renderflex / constraints unbounded error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718208/2301224

Answer (score 8, accepted):

// The solution to your problem is to make the Listview non using scrollable and set shrinkwrap to true. Then wrap the first column in SingleChildScrollView. You don't need Expanded or Flexible Widget for this approach.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = productsData.items;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.info_outline,
          ),
        ),
        title: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/logo.png',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          // mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 140,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26.0),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: const [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15.0,
                    top: 20.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Place Order',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: 10,
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
                products[i].id,
                products[i].name,
                products[i].size,
                products[i].price,
                products[i].image,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you don't need the `SingleChildScrollView` widget. Just remove it. The `listView` is built with a scroll behaviour, you dont need to add it.

Please, let me know if you meant something else and I can help.

If you still have the `Renderflex` error, then wrap your `Column` widget inside a `Flexible` widget

```
Flexible(child: Column(children:[..
```

Comment: HI @Canada2000, I agree. the listview is scrollable. but I want the container above it to also scroll up with it

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Then, keep the SingleChildScrollView and add the Flexible widget on the Column widget, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach among thousands of solutions, it consists of nesting one listview inside another. If you wish you can make the listview.builder horizontal.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ionicons/ionicons.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../widgets/product_item.dart';
import '../providers/products.dart';

class ProductsOverviewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductsOverviewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productsData = Provider.of<Products>(context);
    final products = productsData.items;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(
            Ionicons.notifications_outline,
          ),
        ),
        title: SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/logo.png',
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Ionicons.cart_outline,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 140,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(26.0),
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: const [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 15.0,
                    top: 20.0,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Place Order',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                primary: false,
                itemCount: products.length,
                itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => ProductItem(
                  products[i].id,
                  products[i].name,
                  products[i].size,
                  products[i].price,
                  products[i].image,
                ),
            )
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```