# Flutter unbounded height error if using Spacer in Column inside another Column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-column

I am stuck... This is my code broken down:

```
 Column(
    children: [
      Column(
        children: [
          Text('Whyy'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('crash?'),
        ],
      ),
      Text('ok'),
    ],
  ),
```

This crashes with the error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
>
> When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height
> constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try
> to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on
> a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to
> fill the remaining space in the vertical direction. These two
> directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its
> child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.

But why? Why on earth is this crashing? The `Parent-Column` is inside a `Scaffold`s `body`.

What am I missing here?

Let me know if you need any more information!

Comment: Details on Flutter's layout algorithm and how/why this exception happens (and how to solve it): https://stackoverflow.com/a/66718208/2301224

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the inner column does not have any constraint on its height, so the `Spacer` widget can take an infinitely large space. You can set an actual constraint on the inner column's height by wrapping it with an `Expanded` (or any other height constraining widget like `SizedBox`):

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text('No'),
          Spacer(),
          Text('crash!'),
        ],
      ),
    ),
    Text('ok'),
  ],
),
```