# Building page with ListView and ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter

I have problem building one page with ListView and ExpansionTile.
I have DefaultTabController page, in one tab page I represent list of items.
When you reach end of this list there should be ExpansionTile, and when it openes it should appear another items list. Everything should be scroll-able and without height limitation (if it is possible).
Something like that:

```
Container(
    child: Column(
        children: [
        Scrollbar(child: ListView.builder()),
        ExpansionTile(children: [Scrollbar(child: ListView.builder())]
        ]
    )
);
```

I have tried use Expanded Widget but received only errors. The main idea is for the page to be fully filled with items, and when reach the end, expand to another list and continue scrolling.

Comment: What errors did you get?

Comment: Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Comment: Does this help? [vertical-viewport-was-given-unbounded-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50252569/vertical-viewport-was-given-unbounded-height)

Comment: not at all.. I've tried this also but the main problem is I'm using not only ListView on the page