# How to develop different screen sizes?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a private problem and a more general problem.

I have a `container` with some `Text` widgets and I set he's height to

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.26,
```

If i'm in big screen(I'm not talking about Landscape mode/Portait mode) the container looks fine, but if I am at small screen I  have error that there is no space for the text.

How do I get over it?

And more general question, I've also problem with the space between widgets(big screen there is too much space, small screen there is no space etc)

What is the best solution for this problem(Develop for different screen sizes)

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704497/how-to-make-flutter-app-responsive-according-to-different-screen-size?rq=1