# How to make text change its font size in different screen ratio?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm writing a simple coupon application in Flutter, but I'm struggling with a text widget. I'd like it to be responsive, so when I open my application on a phone with a different screen ration, it should look the same.

How I intend it to look like: 
[image]

How it looks on a phone with 19:9 screen ratio:
[image]

18:9 screen ratio
[image]

My code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import '../../helpers/makdolan.dart';

class GeneratedCouponScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final String couponImage;

  GeneratedCouponScreen({Key key, @required this.couponImage}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var _makdolan = Makdolan();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('DATA WYDANIA:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Text(_makdolan.calculateDate(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0))
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text('UNIKALNY KOD:', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                      Text(_makdolan.calculateUniqueCode(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0))
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              Image.asset(couponImage),
              SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              AutoSizeText.rich(
                TextSpan(
                  text: 'Kupon ten upoważnia do jednokrotnego odbioru produktu gratis przy kolejnym dowolnym zakupie z oferty klasycznej. Kupon ten ważny jest przez 7 dni od czasu jego wygenerowania i może być zrealizowany w dowolnej restauracji Makdolan w Polsce z wyłączeniem restauracji znajdujących się na terenie Portu Lotniczego im. Fryderyka Chopina w Warszawie oraz Portu Lotniczego im. Lecha Wałęsy w Gdańsku. Szczegółowy regulamin ankiety „Opinia Gości" znajduje się na stronie ',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  children: [
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'www.makdolan.pl ',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffffc300), decoration: TextDecoration.underline)
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'w sekcji ',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
                    ),
                    TextSpan(
                      text: 'Regulaminy',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffffc300), decoration: TextDecoration.underline)
                    )
                  ]
                ),
                maxFontSize: 14.0,
              ),
              Spacer(),
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  height: 95.0,
                  color: Color(0xffffc300),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('DRUKUJ /', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0)),
                        Text('ZAPISZ JAKO PDF', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0),)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              ),
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  height: 95.0,
                  color: Color(0xffffc300),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text('PRZEŚLIJ KUPON', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0)),
                        Text('(WYSYŁKA W CIĄGU 24 GODZIN)', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),)
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make flutter app responsive according to different screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704497/how-to-make-flutter-app-responsive-according-to-different-screen-size)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Flexible/Expanded widget to allocate the space for each widget in a column. This should make your column responsive. Also try to put the text widget inside a FittedBox widget so that the text size is responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **MediaQuery** or **AspectRatio** class see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49806752/5034248