# How to resize flutter widgets depending on screen size?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm a beginner with flutter and I found this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel that I want to use. I'm trying to use it for a flutter web app. I went and ran the example and it works but have an issue when I maximize the window, it doesn't look good; big circles, doesn't look the same as it does when it's in a small window(Sizing issue, scaling is bad):

[image: Maximized on an ultrawide monitor]

I tried to use the AspectRatio widget and it looked better but it's still to big. I'm not sure how to use aspect ratio properly anyway but is there another way to fix it?  TLDR; I want the calendar to be readable and scale depending on the size of the screen.
Here's the code from the example btw:

````
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart'
    show CalendarCarousel;
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event_list.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show DateFormat;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'dooboolab flutter calendar',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or press Run > Flutter Hot Reload in IntelliJ). Notice that the
        // counter didn't reset back to zero; the application is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Calendar Carousel Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
  DateTime _currentDate2 = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
  String _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(DateTime(2019, 2, 3));
  DateTime _targetDateTime = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
//  List<DateTime> _markedDate = [DateTime(2018, 9, 20), DateTime(2018, 10, 11)];
  static Widget _eventIcon = new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1000)),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.person,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  );

  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(
    events: {
      new DateTime(2019, 2, 10): [
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 1',
          icon: _eventIcon,
          dot: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 5.0,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 2',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 3',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ),
      ],
    },
  );

  CalendarCarousel _calendarCarousel, _calendarCarouselNoHeader;

  @override
  void initState() {
    /// Add more events to _markedDateMap EventList
    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2019, 2, 25),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 25),
          title: 'Event 5',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 4',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.addAll(new DateTime(2019, 2, 11), [
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 1',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 2',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 3',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
    ]);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Example with custom icon
    _calendarCarousel = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
//          weekDays: null, /// for pass null when you do not want to render weekDays
      headerText: 'Custom Header',
      weekFormat: true,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: 200.0,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      showIconBehindDayText: true,
//          daysHaveCircularBorder: false, /// null for not rendering any border, true for circular border, false for rectangular border
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      markedDateShowIcon: true,
      markedDateIconMaxShown: 2,
      selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      markedDateIconBuilder: (event) {
        return event.icon;
      },
      minSelectedDate: _currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: 360)),
      maxSelectedDate: _currentDate.add(Duration(days: 360)),
      todayButtonColor: Colors.transparent,
      todayBorderColor: Colors.green,
      markedDateMoreShowTotal:
          true, // null for not showing hidden events indicator
//          markedDateIconMargin: 9,
//          markedDateIconOffset: 3,
    );

    /// Example Calendar Carousel without header and custom prev & next button
    _calendarCarouselNoHeader = CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      todayBorderColor: Colors.green,
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate2 = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      daysHaveCircularBorder: true,
      showOnlyCurrentMonthDate: false,
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
      weekFormat: false,
//      firstDayOfWeek: 4,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: 420.0,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      targetDateTime: _targetDateTime,
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      markedDateCustomShapeBorder: CircleBorder(
        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow)
      ),
      markedDateCustomTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      showHeader: false,
      todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // markedDateShowIcon: true,
      // markedDateIconMaxShown: 2,
      // markedDateIconBuilder: (event) {
      //   return event.icon;
      // },
      // markedDateMoreShowTotal:
      //     true,
      todayButtonColor: Colors.yellow,
      selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      minSelectedDate: _currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: 360)),
      maxSelectedDate: _currentDate.add(Duration(days: 360)),
      prevDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
      inactiveDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.tealAccent,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
      onCalendarChanged: (DateTime date) {
        this.setState(() {
          _targetDateTime = date;
          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
        });
      },
      onDayLongPressed: (DateTime date) {
        print('long pressed date $date');
      },
    );

    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              //custom icon
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: _calendarCarousel,
              ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
              //custom icon without header
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 30.0,
                  bottom: 16.0,
                  left: 16.0,
                  right: 16.0,
                ),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                      _currentMonth,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                      ),
                    )),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('PREV'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(_targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month -1);
                          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text('NEXT'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _targetDateTime = DateTime(_targetDateTime.year, _targetDateTime.month +1);
                          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                        });
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: _calendarCarouselNoHeader,
              ), //
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}```
````

Comment: use the `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` values to get the screen width and height respectively and size your widgets accordingly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make flutter app responsive according to different screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704497/how-to-make-flutter-app-responsive-according-to-different-screen-size)

Comment: @LoVe my question is where would I use it at in the example?

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to fetch the parent widget's dimension and adjust the children widgets' dimensions to fit.

From your sample, I've added height and width parameter requirement to create calendarCarousel widgets. The height and width parameters used on the calendar widgets came from `LayoutBuilder`.

Every time the browser window is resized, Flutter rebuilds the screen calling `Widget build()`, rebuilding the UI.

[image: demo]

Complete code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/flutter_calendar_carousel.dart'
    show CalendarCarousel;
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event.dart';
import 'package:flutter_calendar_carousel/classes/event_list.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart' show DateFormat;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'dooboolab flutter calendar',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Calendar Carousel Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _currentDate = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
  DateTime _currentDate2 = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
  String _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(DateTime(2019, 2, 3));
  DateTime _targetDateTime = DateTime(2019, 2, 3);
//  List<DateTime> _markedDate = [DateTime(2018, 9, 20), DateTime(2018, 10, 11)];
  static Widget _eventIcon = new Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(1000)),
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0)),
    child: new Icon(
      Icons.person,
      color: Colors.amber,
    ),
  );

  EventList<Event> _markedDateMap = new EventList<Event>(
    events: {
      new DateTime(2019, 2, 10): [
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 1',
          icon: _eventIcon,
          dot: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 1.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            height: 5.0,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 2',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 3',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ),
      ],
    },
  );

  // CalendarCarousel _calendarCarousel, _calendarCarouselNoHeader;

  @override
  void initState() {
    /// Add more events to _markedDateMap EventList
    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2019, 2, 25),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 25),
          title: 'Event 5',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.add(
        new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
        new Event(
          date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 10),
          title: 'Event 4',
          icon: _eventIcon,
        ));

    _markedDateMap.addAll(new DateTime(2019, 2, 11), [
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 1',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 2',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
      new Event(
        date: new DateTime(2019, 2, 11),
        title: 'Event 3',
        icon: _eventIcon,
      ),
    ]);
    super.initState();
  }

  _calendarCarousel(double calendarHeight, double calendarWidth) {
    return CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
//          weekDays: null, /// for pass null when you do not want to render weekDays
      headerText: 'Custom Header',
      weekFormat: true,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: calendarHeight,
      width: calendarWidth,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      showIconBehindDayText: true,
//          daysHaveCircularBorder: false, /// null for not rendering any border, true for circular border, false for rectangular border
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      markedDateShowIcon: true,
      markedDateIconMaxShown: 2,
      selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      markedDateIconBuilder: (event) {
        return event.icon;
      },
      minSelectedDate: _currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: 360)),
      maxSelectedDate: _currentDate.add(Duration(days: 360)),
      todayButtonColor: Colors.transparent,
      todayBorderColor: Colors.green,
      markedDateMoreShowTotal:
          true, // null for not showing hidden events indicator
//          markedDateIconMargin: 9,
//          markedDateIconOffset: 3,
    );
  }

  _calendarCarouselNoHeader(double calendarHeight, double calendarWidth) {
    return CalendarCarousel<Event>(
      todayBorderColor: Colors.green,
      onDayPressed: (DateTime date, List<Event> events) {
        this.setState(() => _currentDate2 = date);
        events.forEach((event) => print(event.title));
      },
      daysHaveCircularBorder: true,
      showOnlyCurrentMonthDate: false,
      weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      thisMonthDayBorderColor: Colors.grey,
      weekFormat: false,
//      firstDayOfWeek: 4,
      markedDatesMap: _markedDateMap,
      height: calendarHeight,
      width: calendarWidth,
      selectedDateTime: _currentDate2,
      targetDateTime: _targetDateTime,
      customGridViewPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      markedDateCustomShapeBorder:
          CircleBorder(side: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow)),
      markedDateCustomTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      showHeader: false,
      todayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // markedDateShowIcon: true,
      // markedDateIconMaxShown: 2,
      // markedDateIconBuilder: (event) {
      //   return event.icon;
      // },
      // markedDateMoreShowTotal:
      //     true,
      todayButtonColor: Colors.yellow,
      selectedDayTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      minSelectedDate: _currentDate.subtract(Duration(days: 360)),
      maxSelectedDate: _currentDate.add(Duration(days: 360)),
      prevDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
      inactiveDaysTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.tealAccent,
        fontSize: 16,
      ),
      onCalendarChanged: (DateTime date) {
        this.setState(() {
          _targetDateTime = date;
          _currentMonth = DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
        });
      },
      onDayLongPressed: (DateTime date) {
        print('long pressed date $date');
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        // use LayoutBuilder to fetch the parent widget's constraints
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            var parentHeight = constraints.maxHeight;
            var parentWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
            debugPrint('Max height: $parentHeight, max width: $parentWidth');
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  //custom icon
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    // set calendar widget size percentage
                    child: _calendarCarousel(parentHeight * 0.2, parentWidth),
                  ),
                  //custom icon without header
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 30.0,
                      bottom: 16.0,
                      left: 16.0,
                      right: 16.0,
                    ),
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                            child: Text(
                          _currentMonth,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                          ),
                        )),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('PREV'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _targetDateTime = DateTime(_targetDateTime.year,
                                  _targetDateTime.month - 1);
                              _currentMonth =
                                  DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                          child: Text('NEXT'),
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              _targetDateTime = DateTime(_targetDateTime.year,
                                  _targetDateTime.month + 1);
                              _currentMonth =
                                  DateFormat.yMMM().format(_targetDateTime);
                            });
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                    // set calendar widget size percentage
                    child: _calendarCarouselNoHeader(parentHeight * 0.8, parentWidth),
                  ), //
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Update: You can also use [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to achieve similar function.

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size ;
  if (screenSize.width > layoutSize){
    return Widget(); 
  } else {
    return Widget(); /// Widget if doesn't match the size
  }
}
```

Comment: The `MediaQuery.of(context).size` value is good if your widget's size is same as the size of the device. If your widget is small or doesn't fit the whole screen, using LayoutBuilder is better at this point.