# How to get a standard screen size of devices that works in ios and android both devices in a flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I will use full-size background images in my flutter app on some screen like(login, signup)background.
this image is static(means I will not customize this by using MediaQuery or any other code),
but I will still confuse that what size is proper for all devices(android, ios both)
I saw some documents that define, for particular device OS like android(mdpi,hdpi etc).
also same as Ios,
but what I will prefer in a flutter app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704497/how-to-make-flutter-app-responsive-according-to-different-screen-size?rq=1

Comment: @rstrelba i already read this,but i need a standard screen size,that i will apply in image size.
and also my images is static sizes(so if i resize this by code(mediaQuery),may be there pixel distroyed).