# Flutter different screen size

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter project but having problem to make the widgets and texts to fit different phone screens. Tried looking for answers on youtube but I could not get any. Your help is appreciated. Thanks.[rt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pjNu.jpg)

Comment: Please checkout this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704497/how-to-make-flutter-app-responsive-according-to-different-screen-size

Comment: You have to use media query for that `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` and `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` inside the `Widget build(BuildContext context){}` function.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources for your need.

For **responsive layout**,

- https://medium.com/flutter-community/tagged/responsive-design
- https://medium.com/@TidingsSP/flutter-responsive-widget-development-using-a-modular-approach-bf8d63838c76
- https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_framework (responsive layout plugin)
- https://pub.dev/packages/sizer (responsive layout plugin)

For **responsive font**,

- https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text ( best option if you wanna resize font automatically based on parent widget's size )

For **responsive widget**,

- Consider using `Flexible`, `Expanded`, `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`, `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` for widgets' dimensions instead of fixed sizes.
- Use `FittedBox`, `LayoutBuilder`.

**Have fun!!**