# How to round a number in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to round a double.

```
Double x = 5.56753;
x.toStringAsFixed(2);
```

When i put this, it gives 5.57000.
But i want to get 5.57. How do i get it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

there is `num` class contained function `round():`

[Num](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/num-class.html)

```
 double numberToRound = 5.56753;
    print(numberToRound.round()); 
    //prints 6
```

If you want decimals

```
double n = num.parse(numberToRound.toStringAsFixed(2));
  print(n);
  //prints 5.57
```

[check comment sujestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/66840734/3002719)

Comment: At the time of posting this comment (i.e. 28 March 2021) this solution still violated the well-known "***numbers ending with 5***" rounding rule. See this answer => [ https://stackoverflow.com/a/66840734/3002719 ] for a DART solution that adheres to the number 5 round rule.

Answer (score 9):

For rounding doubles checkout: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/double/round.html

Rounding won't work in your case because docs says:

- Returns the `integer` closest to this.

So it will give `6` instead `5.57`.

Your solution:

```
double x = 5.56753;
String roundedX = x.toStringAsFixed(2);
print(roundedX);
```

Comment: He can not accept as his rep is low

Comment: Anybody can accept - upvotes require 15 reputation, but accepting can happen with 1 reputation.