# Problem when try to convert double in string with toString()

Tags: flutter

I have a problem when I want to display a double value in `flutter`. I use `Text` widget and I need to transform my double 0.00 in a string to display it in the widget Text. The problem is it returns "null".
I want to display "BALANCE: 0.00 €", I have the 0.00 stored in double var but I can't display the value with Text Widget. Here is my code :

```
 Container(
                child: Text(
                "BALANCE: "+globals.balance.toString()+" €",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    color: Colors.white),
               ),
          ),
```

Result is : BALANCE : null €

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you round a double in Dart to a given degree of precision AFTER the decimal point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419255/how-do-you-round-a-double-in-dart-to-a-given-degree-of-precision-after-the-decim)

Answer (score 0):

you can check if null and convert it to 0 like this:

```
"BALANCE : "+(globals.balance??0).toStringAsFixed(2)+" €",
```

Comment: Your "??" after globals.balance it is like if global.balance==null then 0 ???

Comment: Yes, "??" is a null check operator.