# parse string to double with 2 decimal places in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert string to decimal in flutter with two decimal places

```
_accountStatementStore.totalIn = "100";
 Text(
              "${double.parse(_accountStatementStore.totalIn!)}",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  color: Colors.green[700]),
            ),
```

the result is **100.0**

How can I achieve **100.00** ?

Comment: This post might be able to point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419255/how-do-you-round-a-double-in-dart-to-a-given-degree-of-precision-after-the-decim

Answer (score 5):

Please refer to below code

[code snippet](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f91512867db5a6230a6f5f0090a82948)

For more info on toStringAsFixed.
Please refer to this [link description](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html)

```
  String num = "19";
  double val = double.parse(num);
    print('Result: ${val.toStringAsFixed(2)}');
```

```
Output:
Result: 19.00
```