# toStringAsFixed() returns a round-up value of a given number in Dart

Tags: dart, double, precision

I want to get one decimal place of a `double` in `Dart`. I use the `toStringAsFixed()` method to get it, but it returns a round-up value.

```
double d1 = 1.151;
double d2 = 1.150;

print('$d1 is ${d1.toStringAsFixed(1)}');
print('$d2 is ${d2.toStringAsFixed(1)}');

Console output:
1.151 is 1.2
1.15 is 1.1
```

How can I get it without a round-up value? Like `1.1` for `1.151` too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you would want a `double` that's approximately 1.199 to be printed as 1.1 and not 1.2?  Why?

Comment: @jamesdlin Absolutely yes. Why? Let's say it's a requirement of my next app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Not* rounding seems highly questionable to me<sup>1</sup>, but if you *really* want to truncate the string representation without rounding, then I'd take the string representation, find the decimal point, and create the appropriate substring.

There are a few potential pitfalls:

- The value might be so large that its normal string representation is in exponential form.  Note that `double.toStringAsFixed` just returns the exponential form anyway for such large numbers, so maybe do the same thing.
- The value might be so small that its normal string representation is in exponential form. `double.toStringAsFixed` already handles this, so instead of using `double.toString`, use `double.toStringAsFixed` with the maximum number of fractional digits.
- The value might not have a decimal point at all (e.g. NaN, +infinity, -infinity).  Just return those values as they are.

```dart
extension on double {
  // Like [toStringAsFixed] but truncates (toward zero) to the specified
  // number of fractional digits instead of rounding.
  String toStringAsTruncated(int fractionDigits) {
    // Require same limits as [toStringAsFixed].
    assert(fractionDigits >= 0);
    assert(fractionDigits <= 20);
    
    if (fractionDigits == 0) {
      return truncateToDouble().toString();
    }

    // [toString] will represent very small numbers in exponential form.
    // Instead use [toStringAsFixed] with the maximum number of fractional
    // digits.
    var s = toStringAsFixed(20);

    // [toStringAsFixed] will still represent very large numbers in
    // exponential form.
    if (s.contains('e')) {
      // Ignore values in exponential form.
      return s;
    }

    // Ignore unrecognized values (e.g. NaN, +infinity, -infinity).
    var i = s.indexOf('.');
    if (i == -1) {
      return s;
    }

    return s.substring(0, i + fractionDigits + 1);
  }
}

void main() {
  var values = [
    1.151,
    1.15,
    1.1999,
    -1.1999,
    1.0,
    1e21,
    1e-20,
    double.nan,
    double.infinity,
    double.negativeInfinity,
  ];

  for (var v in values) {
    print(v.toStringAsTruncated(1));
  }
}
```

Another approach one might consider is to multiply by `pow(10, fractionalDigits)`, use `double.truncateToDouble`, divide by the power-of-10 used earlier, and then use `.toStringAsFixed(fractionalDigits)`.  That could work for human-scaled values, but it could generate unexpected results for very large values due to precision loss from floating-point arithmetic. (This approach would work if you used [`package:decimal`](https://pub.dev/packages/decimal) instead of `double`, though.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Not rounding seems especially bad given that [using `double`s to represent fractional base-10 numbers is inherently imprecise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68980598/).  For example, since the closest IEEE-754 double-precision floating number to 0.7 is 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875, do you really want `0.7.toStringAsTruncated(1)` to return `'0.6'` instead of `'0.7'`?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I know it's not that much reasonable to not round up the number, especially with cases you mentioned in the note. But I specifically use this for representing the views, likes and comments of the posts in my next social app. For example, I want to represent 1195 likes as 1.1K likes. I don't know if it's still a good idea to truncate the decimal part or round it to look like 1.2K. I would appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @sm_sayedi Okay, that makes sense and seems like a fair reason to always round down.  FWIW, StackOverflow seems to round-to-nearest.