# Result of divided by 100 on Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to find the result of dividing by 100 from the `TextFromField` input. Here is my code:

```
TextFormField(
  controller: _percentController,
  onChange: (text) {
    _setPercent(text);
  }
)

void _setPercent(String? text) {
  var percent = double.tryParse(text ?? '') ?? 0.0;
  print('percent $percent');
  percent = percent / 100;
  print('new percent ${percent}');
}
```

If input `0.001` until `0.005` result is `0.00001` until `0.00005`

If input `0.007` until `0.007` result is `0.00007000000000000001`

If input `0.008` result is `0.00008`

If input `0.009` result is `0.00008999999999999999`

What happened to my code? There is a bug or maybe something wrong with my code?

Comment: that link is explain what real happen with my code, so then how to resolve it in dart code?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68980598/.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of floating point.  Has nothing to do with Dart.  Been like this for decades, for necessary reasons.