How to round all numbers to 2 in the whole flutter project?
I am working on a flutter app with banking numbers, and therefore only needs two decimal numbers. Is there a way to round every number automatically in my whole project at once ?
The idea is to not use amount.toStringAsFixed(2) all the time.

it would use extension on model class. You can also use it domain(while parsing model but I won't do it)

If your app involves money, you should avoid internally storing doubles anyway. Rounding a double to 2 decimal places and storing the result as a double is a nonsensical operation.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68980598/

You can make use of dart extension methods.
Define the logic for formatting numbers in an extension.
extension PriceStringExt on num {
  String get priceStr {
    return toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}

Use it anywhere in your project.
int price = 12;
price.priceStr;


Yes you can create one common method for this like below
Access amountFix every where in your whole code like below:
void main() {
  print(CommonMethod.amountFix(125.599));
}

Your common method declare below:
class CommonMethod {
  static amountFix(double amount) {
    return amount.toStringAsFixed(2);
  }
}

you can access in widget as well like below:
   Center(
      child: Text(
        CommonMethod.amountFix(125.599),
      ),
    ),


They're trying to avoid calling a function like that every time they need two decimal places. It needs to convert to two decimal places automatically.
